# NgZone or ChangeDetectorRef not working in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I´m using the cordova-plugin-document-scanner plugin in my ionic 3 iOS App which allows me to take a photo with some additional features. Everything works fine and I get the fileURI in the success callback (file:///...).

After taking a Photo, I´m not able to update the DOM to show the image in my view home.html. I tried also to update a simple text (test), but it also do not work.

I´ve tried it with ngZone and also with ChangeDetectorRef. Both give me:

```
Error in Success callbackId: Scan683272023 : TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.test = ('changed')')
```

**home.html**

```
<p>{{test}}</p>
<img [src]="image | safePipe: 'url'" #imageResult />
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
...
declare var scan:any;
...
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('imageResult') private imageResult: ElementRef;
  public imageURI: string = '';
  test: string = 'initial';
  _zone: any;
  image: string = '';
 ...

constructor(
...
   private camera: Camera,
   public changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
   public platform: Platform,
   public actionsheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {
    this._zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false }
   );
}

takePicture() {
    scan.scanDoc(0, this.onSuccess, this.onFail);
};

onSuccess(imageURI) {
      this.test = ('changed');
      this.image = imageURI;
      this.imageResult.nativeElement.src = this.image;
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
 }

 also tried:
 onSuccess(imageURI) {
       this._zone.run(() => {this.test = 'updated';
       ...
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had ‘this’ issue - it was not pointing to the home component if onSuccess method is called in the callback.

To fix you could do assignment via fat arrow:

onSuccess = () => { your code here }

And the reason your answer works is cause you used fat arrow function which doesnt create new “this” context.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

```
takePicture() {

    this._images = true;

    scan.scanDoc(0,
      (onSuccess) => {
        this.image = onSuccess;
        this.imageResult.nativeElement.src = this.image;
      });

  }
```